# Same version of dotnet.exe and different output of dotnet --version

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Two environments, Windows 10 desktop and Windows ServerCore LTSC2019 docker container,
with the same version of `dotnet.exe` tool installed, but `dotnet --version` issued on both gives different output.

#### Windows 10 (desktop)

It is a development environment with Visual Studio 2022, .NET SDK-s, Windows SDK-s, etc.

The location and version of `dotnet.exe`:

[image]

The `dotnet --version` output:

[image]

#### Windows ServerCore 2019

It is a Docker container with [ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) installed from the recommended Hosting Bundle.

The location and version of `dotnet.exe`:

[image]

The `dotnet --version` output:

[image]

#### Question

Why the `dotnet --version` output is different?

Why the `dotnet --version` on the container is basically useless?

Comment: What do you get on the Windows server installation when you run `dotnet --info` ?  `dotnet --version' returns the versions of SDKs installed. You might have installed a container that just has the run-time installed, which in many cases is all that you need, especially in a production environment.

Comment: Yes, I'm convinced I made it clear the container is with just the runtime installed. It does not matter what is needed in a production environment. It is not what my question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured the answer myself:

TL;TR: `dotnet.exe --version` command returns version of .NET SDK available/used in current environment. It does not return version of the `dotnet.exe` program itself.

In case of environment with .NET or ASP.NET runtime only, there are no SDK-s:
[image]

Hence, there is nothing to return by `dotnet --version`.

Unlike in case of environment where both, runtimes and SDK-s are deployed:
[image]

Alternatively, `dotnet.exe` deployed by .NET or ASP.NET runtime package is slightly different to `dotnet.exe` deployed by SDK packages, such that the latter understands the `--version` switch.